# How to use multiple values to compare in powershell

Tags: powershell

In simple words I am trying -

```
$animal = "cat", "dog", "rabbit"
$animal -contains "dog" # -----> Getting true, which is working!
```

However, when I try to check multiple values like -

```
$animal -contains "dog" -and "bat" # --> still getting a "True" response.
```

How can I check multiple values using contains operator?

Comment: `-contains` and `-in` can compare a collection against a scalar (single value). There are many different ways to solve this tho. What specifically do you want as output? just a true / false if ALL elements exist in the collection or if you could be more specific in this it can help us uderstand

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to use it in an IF statement. if(($Status -ne "Strong") -and ($Method -contains "abc" -or "def")) { write-host...}}

Comment: Related PowerShell propose: [`#2132` The `-Like` and `-NotLike` comparison operators should allow for an array of values](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean expressions work a little differently. You need this:

```
$animal -contains "dog" -and $animal -contains "bat"
```

You could also put "dog" and "bat" in their own array, and loop through the array.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Joel Coehoorn's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74211024/15339544), you can use the [`IsSupersetOf(IEnumerable<T>)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.issupersetof?view=net-7.0) from the [`HashSet<T>` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0).

```
$animal = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]] ('cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'),
    [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase
)

$animal.IsSupersetOf([string[]] ('dog', 'bat')) # => False
$animal.IsSupersetOf([string[]] ('dog', 'cat')) # => True
```